# VSCODE & SumatraPDF InverseSearch Problem

Tags: forward-inverse-search

Today, I tried to make inverse_Search from sumatraPDF to Vscode(latex workshop). In the column "Set inverse search command-line" in sumatraPDF,I write  "`E:\VSCODE\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe"  -g "%f":%l`", which is my path of `Code.exe`. However, when I click in a pdf file, there is a tip that shows: "`EPERM:operation not permitted,mkdir'c:\Users\16323\.vscode\extensions.Please make sure the following directories writable: C:\Users\16323\AppData\Roaming\Code C:\Users\16323\.vscode\extensions'`".
I think the cause of the problem is that I changed the Installation location of the vscode plugin to "`E:\VSCODE`" and create a symbolic link to the directory to save the space of disk C.
What can I do to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

For the records, here is a solution to this question, extracted from this [forum discussion](https://forum.sumatrapdfreader.org/t/inverse-search-not-performed-for-vs-code-exe/4486/).

**IMPORTANT:** For the reverse search to work, and only for the first time, one must close all SumatraPDF instances and use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> hotkey from the LaTeX file to open the corresponding PDF in SumatraPDF. Without this step, double-clicking on the PDF in SumatraPDF opens the `cli.js` file instead of the LaTeX file.

This gives proper forward and inverse search with [SumatraPDF](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/) and [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/), using the fantastic [LaTeX Workshop](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=James-Yu.latex-workshop) extension:

- Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to jump from the LaTeX editor in VSCode to the PDF location in SumatraPDF.
- Use `mouse double click` to jump from the PDF in SumatraPDF to the LaTeX line in VSCode.

In `settings.json` of VSCode, include the following lines

```
"latex-workshop.view.pdf.viewer": "external",
"latex-workshop.view.pdf.external.viewer.command": "C:/Program Files/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF.exe",
"latex-workshop.view.pdf.external.synctex.command": "C:/Program Files/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF.exe",
"latex-workshop.view.pdf.external.synctex.args": ["-forward-search", "%TEX%", "%LINE%", "-reuse-instance","%PDF%"],
```

Then, in SumatraPDF one sets the inverse-search command as follows, while replacing `PathToCode` with the real path to VSCode:

```
"C:\PathToCode\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" "C:\PathToCode\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\cli.js" --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node -r -g "%f:%l"
```

[image]